# Which wallets support a multi signature transaction?

Tags: wallets, multisignature

I have an address with some coins and I want to set it up as a multi-signature wallet using 2 of 3. Which wallets support this feature and is there a good tutorial for this? I want to to split control of my funds with me and 2 other friends.

When I make a transaction, do their wallets also get alerted that I made a transaction so they can approve it? Or it doesnt work like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for this ["Wallet account"](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/wiki/Wallet-Contract), i will give you more information about this in this links:

- [Reddit info](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/45xeiw/whats_the_difference_between_account_and_wallet/?st=irkkzssp&sh=789d99189)
- [Some oficial info](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/frequently-asked-questions/frequently-asked-questions.html#what-s-the-difference-between-account-and-wallet-contract)

These types of contracts allow you to have a wallet with multiple accounts and establish a minimum of signatures to carry out transactions as well as establish a limit of expenses per day.

Answer (score 0):

ConsenSys has developed a multisig wallet that you can find on GitHub:
https://github.com/ConsenSys/MultiSigWallet

You will find also find more details in their post about it:
 https://blog.gnosis.pm/release-of-new-multisig-wallet-59b6811f7edc

> Multisig wallets were developed early on by the Ethereum Foundation
>   (EF) to protect their own funds. Gavin Wood wrote the first
>   implementation, which can be found [here](https://github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/blob/master/wallet/wallet.sol)

You could also use Mist as a multisig wallet. See [here](https://github.com/PeterChauYEG/ethereum-guides/blob/master/create-ethereum-multisignature-wallet.md).